# Como disparar um evento quando uma List é alterada?

Tags: c#

Queria saber se é possível e, caso seja, como disparar um evento quando uma `List` é alterada, para as seguintes alterações:

- Um elemento é removido;
- Um elemento é adicionado;
- Um elemento tem seu índice alterado;

Existe alguma forma de disparar um evento quando isso ocorrer?

Comment: Como você altera o índice do elemento?

Comment: Use uma ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, mas não é usando exatamente `List<>`. Use no lugar [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).

Basicamente, [a classe tem dois eventos que fazem o que você precisa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms668610(v=vs.110).aspx), mas você só usaria [`CollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) para os três casos.

Outra maneira seria usar proxy dinâmico, mas seria recomendado apenas para interceptar casos em que o `ObservableCollection` não consegue agir.